# Tab separated data python

Tags: python, matplotlib, tabs, histogram

Must start that I am very new to Python and very bad at it still, but believe that it will be worth it to learn eventually.

My problem is that I have this device that prints out the values in a .txt but seperated by tabs instead of commas. Ex: 50\t50\t66\t0\t4...

And what I want is just plot a simple Histogram with that data.
I do realise that it should be the simplest thing but somehow I am having trouble with it finding a solution from my python nooby lectures nor can I really word this well enough to hit a search online.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
#import numpy as np

d = open('.txt', 'r')
d.read()

plt.hist(d)
plt.show()
```

PS: numpy is just a remainder from one of my previous exercises

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assign the string result of read() to a variable s:

```
s = d.read()
```

[split](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html) will break your string s into a list of strings:

```
s = s.split("\t")
```

[map](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#map) will apply a function to every element of a list:

```
s = map(float, s)
```

Comment: Be careful with this solution.  It doesn't account for TSV files that have tabs embedded in quoted fields, which the CSV module will take care of for you.  map is one way to convert the numbers, but it might be best to also let the csv reader module handle it.  This of course greatly depends on the complexity of the tabbed file you are trying to read.

Answer (score 1):

No worries, everyone must start somewhere.  You are on the right track, and are correct Python is a great language to learn.  There are many was this can be accomplished, but here is one way.  With the way this example written, it will generate one histogram graph per line in the file.  You can modify or change that behavior if needed.

Please note that the CSV module will take care of converting the data in the file to floats by passing the quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONNUMERIC to the constructor of reader.  This is probably the preferred method to handling number conversion in a CSV / TSV file.

```
import csv
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data_file = open('testme.txt')
tsv_reader = csv.reader(data_file, delimiter='\t',
                        quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONNUMERIC)

for row in tsv_reader:
    plt.hist(row)
    plt.show()
```

I've left out some things such as proper [exception handling](http://docs.python.org/3.4/tutorial/errors.html), and using a [context manager](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0343/) to open to file as is best practice and demonstrated in the [csv module documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html).

Once you learn more about the language, I'd suggest digging into those subjects further.

Comment: Thanks, that is exactly what I actually need in one of my non exercise projects, one of those that I am dweling into Python for. Had you not answered this I would probably have been here again for this very thing in a few weeks.

Answer (score 0):

If you study csv you can handle the file with delimiter='\t' as one of the options. This will change the expected delimiter from ',' to '\t' (tab. All the examples that you study that use the ',' will be handled in the same way.

Comment: Didn't get to csv yet, but it sounds very practical. Will put it on my list of things to look into. Thanks~